# Identify and label clusters of sequential rows of a certain value in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a table of data (below) where I have data organized into Group and values are ordered sequentially. I am trying to identify clusters rows that have identical values/specific values in another column, and then and Label that cluster sequentially, and loop this over the Groups in another column.

I am completely lost on knowing how to create a label for each additional cluster of sequential rows, and then have the label change based on which cluster this is in that particular Group.

As you can see, the desired outcome would be to flag a cluster as one or more rows that have the Value = 1 (in Var 3), and Label each new cluster that occurs in each "Group" as a function of the GroupName + ClusterName + #

[image: Example data and desired outcome in orange.]

Comment: Wats ```#``` in the ```ClusterName``` How it's calculated ??

Comment: @Sushanth, the # in the naming convention is to distinguish each  cluster (if there are multiple) that exist in a single Group. Currently I have it running as Cluster one is the first cluster observed when descending in Order.

Comment: So tats just a running sequence..

Comment: @Sushanth, yes you're correct